# SetInterval affect other function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using set this function and when i click submit button to authenticate to site.
it run but sometimes it doesn't run. i think setInterval function affect this situation. Is it true ? how can i solve this problem ?

```
window.setInterval(function () {
  var path = "../../Content/Images/banners/Banner_0" + sayac + ".jpg"
  $("#mainPic").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $(this).attr("src", path);
    sayac = sayac + 1;
    if (sayac == 7) {
      sayac = 1;
    }
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
  });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: How did you came to conclusion that setInterval is the culprit? Have you tried removing the setInterval and then tried? Could you share more details or code for authentication?

Comment: i don't catch this situation every time. i really don't understand what it do.

Comment: How big are you jpg files? You have fadeOut/fadeIn with "slow" duration (each 600 ms).

Comment: they are about 250 kb

Comment: Just try commenting out the setInterval function and check multiple times if form submission is still errorneous?

Comment: i see this probmlem when i try many times. i am entering username and password and click submit button then my page begin loading, after it ends. and one second or two second later it enters the site :)

Comment: So authentication has finished and if js function don't end it couldn't enter the site

Comment: This part of code with setInterval function works without problems (except that variable _sayac_ has to be defined). I tested it with 4 Mb images and longer duration for fadeOut/fadeIn and setInterval triggers regularly on 5 seconds. It must be something else. You mention some autenthication. It could be that part of code. And do you work locally on your system or on some remote server?

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no way the setInterval influences the submit mechanism.

At most it can delay the submit by an insignificant amount of time if the submit event is triggered while the function in setInterval is running. If the function would take a long time to return, it could become a problem, but your function only triggers an animation, so it returns almost instantly.